# Error redirect domain with https to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, apache2

I can not redirect from one domain to another if there is `https` in the url.

That is, I have to handle all the requests made on the domain `http://www.mywebsite1.net` that must be reindered to the domain `https://www.mywebsite2.com`

With this I manage it safely via htaccess with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that if an url arrives with this `https://www.mywebsite1.net` error page

```
NET :: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

because the SSL certificate is no longer installed on the old domain. So how do I handle this problem?

I hope I was clear enough.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into SNI, Server Name Indication.  If the browser supports it, you can create VHosts according to youre needs (Details: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI)

```
    # Ensure that Apache listens on port 443
    Listen 443

    # Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
    NameVirtualHost *:443

    # Go ahead and accept connections for these vhosts
    # from non-SNI clients
    SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

    <VirtualHost *:443>
      # Because this virtual host is defined first, it will
      # be used as the default if the hostname is not received
      # in the SSL handshake, e.g. if the browser doesn't support
      # SNI.
      DocumentRoot /www/example1
      ServerName   www.mywebsite1.net

      # Other directives here

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
      DocumentRoot /www/example2
      ServerName  www.mywebsite2.com

      # Other directives here

    </VirtualHost>
```

All modern browsers support this feature.  If they don't, you're stuck, since the HTTP-Header Part is encrypted, there is no way to choose the correct vhost early enough.